# Use IMPORTXML to import from multiple URLs at one time

Tags: google-sheets

I have this formula `=IMPORTXML(B3;"//h2")`, where there is a URL in B3.
I want to grab results from at least two URLs at one time, which are in B3 and B4, as I need the results in one column one after another and the number of results is unknown. Neither this:

```
=IMPORTXML(B3:B4;"//h2")
```

nor this:

```
=ArrayFormula(IMPORTXML(B3:B4;"//h2"))
```

is working.

Is there a way or trick to do that?

Comment: I need the results in one column one after another. The number of results is unknown. So, to insert that in one formula would be the best solution.

Answer (score 7):

Please try:

```
=query({IMPORTXML(B3;"//h2");IMPORTXML(B4;"//h2")})
```

Add further terms inside the curly braces to suit.

Comment: Best, best trick ever :). You are google spreadsheet's god! Unfortunately, can't even upvote for the lack of reputation.

Comment: This (omitting `query`) works too:
`={IMPORTXML(B3;"//h2");IMPORTXML(B4;"//h2")}`

Answer (score 2):

simplified [pnuts](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1505120/pnuts) idea:

```
={IMPORTXML(B3;"//h2");IMPORTXML(B4;"//h2")}
```